# Is it possible to detect WASM compiler in code via compiler directives?

Tags: c++, webassembly

Is there a standard `#define` I can detect within my own C++ code that would indicate if WASM is compiling the code?

In C++ on Android I can use `#ifdef __ANDROID__` but I'm not sure for Web Assembly ? I'm actually using emcc compiler so maybe there's a standard `#define` for EMCC compiler...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__wasm__` to detect the Wasm architecture in general or `__wasm32__`/`__wasm64__` to be more precise.  Or you can use `__EMSCRIPTEN__` to specifically detect the emscripten target.

Comment: I went with `#if defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__) || defined(__wasm__) || defined(__wasm32__) || defined(__wasm64__) ... #endif` and it worked.

Comment: Which compilers define these values?